# Laravel 5.2 subtração na mesma coluna

Tags: laravel

Estou começando em Laravel (5.2) e preciso de montar a `query` abaixo no *Builder*! Praticamente ela subtrai o valor anterior da mesma coluna.

Ela funciona normalmente, mas estou migrando para o Laravel.

```
$query = "SELECT tbl_leitura_gas.id_leitura
                ,tbl_leitura_gas.data_leitura
                ,tbl_leitura_gas.valor_leitura
                ,tbl_leitura_gas.data_cadastro
                ,ifnull(valor_leitura -
                        (SELECT mt.valor_leitura
                           FROM tbl_leitura_gas mt
                          WHERE mt.data_leitura < tbl_leitura_gas.data_leitura
                          ORDER BY mt.data_leitura DESC LIMIT 0
                                  ,1)
                       ,0) AS consumo_m3
            FROM tbl_leitura_gas
           ORDER BY tbl_leitura_gas.data_leitura DESC";
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda , Valdir.

Comment: Está utilizando [tag:MySql] como banco de dados certo?

Comment: Estou sim...obrigado pelo contato.

Answer (score 0):

Olá , batalhei um pouco e cheguei nesta expressão, não sei se é a ideal mas está funcionando (acrescentei também uma diferença entre datas)

```
$leitura_gas = DB::table('leitura_gas')
      ->select('id','id_apto', 'valor_leitura', 'data_leitura', 'obs_leitura',
        DB::raw('IFNULL(valor_leitura - (SELECT  mt.valor_leitura FROM leitura_gas mt WHERE mt.data_leitura < leitura_gas.data_leitura ORDER BY mt.data_leitura DESC LIMIT 0,1), 0) AS consumo_m3'),
        DB::raw('DATEDIFF(data_leitura, (SELECT mt.data_leitura FROM leitura_gas mt WHERE mt.data_leitura < leitura_gas.data_leitura ORDER BY mt.data_leitura DESC LIMIT 0,1)) AS consumo_dias'))
      ->orderBy('data_leitura', 'DESC')

      ->where('id_apto', '=', $apto)
      ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(data_leitura)'), '=', $ano_leitura)
```

Comment: Não acho uma boa ideia usar o `DB::raw`. Se um dia quiser migrar de banco, vai ter problemas. Seria melhor usar um `Model mutator and accessor`